# WPF DataGrid - Group Elements in code-behind C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've been trying to figure a way of grouping items in DataGrid in code-behind.
My DataGrid is filled in code-behind from a List collection of custom Objects, what i wanted is to split this Objects in Groups. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use a CollectionView, but the CollectionView *base type* does not support grouping.

To get grouping to work in code you need to use one of the derrived CollectionView types that implements grouping such as:

- ListCollectionView
- BindingListCollectionView

You use it something like this:

```
 ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(myCollection);
 lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("PropertyNameToGroupBy"));
 MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = lcv;
```

Normally when you set a collection directly to the ItemSource, WPF will automatically create a CollectionView for you under the covers.

Bea Stollnitz talks a lot about [CollectionViews on her blog](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/index.php?s=collectionview) if you want more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `DataGrid` to a `CollectionView` that is created from your list of objects. The `CollectionView` supports grouping. This is not really a code-behind solution, but it is very easy to use.

Comment: I know how this can be done from xaml point of view, in my case this will not work as I'm building a custom control that extands to DataGrid class in order to style and organize data and functionality required.

Comment: `DataGrid` uses `ICollectionView` and `CollectionView` implements this interface. Maybe you can get some inspiration from the interactions between `DataGrid` and `ICollectionView`? You might implement your solution by implementing your own `ICollectionView` on your collection of objects.